# setState only setting last input when using object as state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Im trying to create a form with React. This form uses a custom Input component I created various times. In the parent form Im trying to get a complete object with all names and all values of the form:

```
  {inputName: value, inputName2: value2, inputName3: value3}
```

For this, I created a 'component updated' hook, that calls the function property `onNewValue` to send the new value to the parent (two way data binding):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (onNewValue) onNewValue({ name, value });
  }, [value]);
```

The parent form receives the data in the `handleInputChange` function:

```
export default () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = ({
    name,
    value
  }: {
    name: string;
    value: string | number;
  }): void => {
    console.log("handleInputChange", { name, value }); // All elements are logged here successfully
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <Input
          name={"nombre"}
          required={true}
          label={"Nombre"}
          maxLength={30}
          onNewValue={handleInputChange}
        />
        <Input
          name={"apellidos"}
          required={true}
          label={"Apellidos"}
          maxLength={60}
          onNewValue={handleInputChange}
        />
        <Input
          name={"telefono"}
          required={true}
          label={"Teléfono"}
          maxLength={15}
          onNewValue={handleInputChange}
        />
        <Input
          name={"codigoPostal"}
          required={true}
          label={"Código Postal"}
          maxLength={5}
          onNewValue={handleInputChange}
          type={"number"}
        />
      </form>
      State of values: {JSON.stringify(values)}
    </>
  );
};
```

This way all elements from all inputs should be set **on init**:

```
  {"codigoPostal":"","telefono":"","apellidos":"","nombre":""}
```

But for some reason **only the last one** is being set:

```
  {"codigoPostal":""}
```

You can find the bug here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-vx5py

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set state process in React is an asynchronous process. Therefore even if the function is called, `values` has not updated the previous state just yet.

To fix, this you can use the functional version of `setState` which returns the previous state as it's first argument.

```
setValues(values=>({ ...values, [name]: value }));
```

Comment: I accept this because I think the description is the most clear. Thanks! Thought I prefer the `prevValues` or `prevState` nomenclature.

Answer (score 1):

[useState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) doesn't merge the states unlike `this.setState()` in a class.

So better off separate the fields into individual states.

```
const [nombre, setNombre] = useState("")
const [apellidos, setApellidos] = useState("")
// and so on
```

**UPDATE**:

Given `setValue()` is async use previous state during init.

```
setValues((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated and fixed code, look at:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-mm7by

look at:

```
  const handleInputChange = ({
    name,
    value
  }: {
    name: string;
    value: string | number;
  }): void => {
    console.log("handleInputChange", { name, value });
    setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [ list, setList ] = useState( [ ] );
```

correct:

```
 setList ( ( list ) => [ ...list, value ] )
```

avoid use:

```
 setList( [ ...list, value ] )
```